# Change text by Command with VS-Code-Extension

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to implement a second code formatting. This formatting should be executable by an additional command.

I have already registered a `DocumentFormattingEditProvider` and that is fine.

```ts
vscode.languages.registerDocumentFormattingEditProvider({ language: 'sosse' }, {
    provideDocumentFormattingEdits(document: vscode.TextDocument) {
        return formattingAction(document);
    },
});
```

But in my case I need a second formatting action for one-liners, which is executed by an command.
I thought about using:

```ts
vscode.commands.registerCommand(command, callback)
```

But I don't know how to access and change the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't know how to access and change the document.

There's a special variant of `registerCommand()` that I think is exactly what you're looking for: `registerTextEditorCommand()`. From the [API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_commands):

> Text editor commands are different from ordinary commands as they only execute when there is an active editor when the command is called. Also, **the command handler of an editor command has access to the active editor and to an edit-builder.**

That means the `callback` gets passed an instance of a [`TextEditor`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#TextEditor) as well as a [`TextEditorEdit`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#TextEditorEdit).

Comment: For additional information, try this:
https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/11/15/formatters-best-practices