# get currently focus file via VSCode extension API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

There is the steps.

1. select a file or directory in workspaces.
2. exec command via keybindings.
3. get the selected file or directory path in command handler.

Command handler

```
vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.myExtension', function (event) {
  // event is undefined.
  // how to do in here?
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change text by Command with VS-Code-Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904658/change-text-by-command-with-vs-code-extension)

Comment: ^I think `registerTextEditorCommand()` from the answer above is what you're looking for, the callback receives the active editor as a parameter in that case.

Comment: @Gama11 it's well when select a file, but if select a directory, the callback function will not run.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you're after. Is this a command in the context menu of the file explorer?

Comment: If so, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51961457/how-to-get-file-name-or-path-in-vscode-extension-when-user-right-click-on-file-i/51971599#51971599. But the first argument should not be `undefined` in that case.

Comment: @Gama11, by clicking the context menu, can get the file path. But when context menu and keybindings coexist, callback’s argument has two situations. actually, I want to register a command like `explorer.newFile`, so I need to get the focused file's path via keybindings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it

```
 vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.myExtension', function (event) {
  const activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    if(activeEditor){
       //For Getting File Path
       let filePath = activeEditor.document.uri.path;
       
    }
})
```